# NotePad++ regex match and replace and also keep match to convert to different markdown image reference link

Tags: regex, image, hyperlink, markdown, notepad++

I have the following link syntax that needs to be changed:

```
![[afoldernamenolongerneededandwillbedeprecated/somemarkdownfilename_image1.png]]
```

I tried (successfully) with this regex to match:

```
![[].*[\/].*_image[0-9].png[]]]
```

Although I have a hunch it may not be what I should use. I the novice think it may be only good for matching and not replacing. All images are png's, by the way. All filenames have _image in them, prefixed by the markdown file-name.

Desired end format:

```
![image](imagenamefromabovestring1,2,orhowevermanythereare.png)
```

The

```
![]()
```

is a known syntax in markdown to reference images. Images will be populated in subdirectories the program/app will find.

It goes without saying I want to run find and replace recursively on some 4000 files containing image references.

I put up the unfinished substitution example here:
https://regex101.com/r/Bl8HJC/1

So to clarify more on what I need. I need the formerly present folder name gone. I don't need it anymore. Then after the slash comes the name of the image, the syntax of which is always: current filename to be proccessed by NotePad++ recursively (it can be a markdown file named Ab, Aba, Abracadabra, etc.) and this filename always serves as prefix, then comes an underscore and 'image' + a number depending on how many images are linked to the markdown file as attachments. The names of the files to go in an attachment folder will look like this:

```
AB_image3.png
Abracadabra_image2.png
.
.
.
Zodiac_image45.png
```

I am looking for the right syntax as I couldn't figure it out with the dollar sign.

Cheers,

Otto

Comment: Could you please explain the Logic of getting expected output more clearly, thank you.

Comment: I have edited my inquiry, Rav.

Comment: A little unclear; are you saying you may have data like `![[folder\filename_image1.png\filename_image2.png]]` and you need to reshape this?

Comment: @JvdV
No, original link is ![[folder/filename_image.png]]
New one is e.g. ![image](filename_image.png)
Image number can go up to 99 but not more.
Basically I don't need the folder part anymore or it should be changed to assets, which I can do, but the rest I couldn't figure out for multiple documents.

Comment: If there is only 1 directory and the filenames consist of word characters `!\[\[[^\s\/]+\/(\w+_image[0-9]{1,2}\.png)\]\]` https://regex101.com/r/admmjK/1 Else you can also use a non greedy version of matching non whitespace characters `!\[\[\S+?\/(\S+?_image[0-9]{1,2}\.png)\]\]` https://regex101.com/r/YYwDMa/1

Comment: Cheers, mate, all 4000 directories have been taken care of. I appreciate the teaching endevour on your part. Will hopefully make others benefit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your example to get it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/wp0XGj/1). What you needed to do is escape the square brackets so they would be interpreted literally, since they have special meaning in regex, and you needed to use a capture group to store the matching value in `$1` so you could use it in the replacement.

Regular expression:

```
!\[\[.*\/(.*_image[0-9]{1,2}\.png)\]\]
```

Substitution format:

```
![image]\($1\)
```

**Edit**: Question was revised to state that the folder name was unwanted in the final output, so matches are delimited after the final `/` character in the file path.

**Edit 2**: Support for file numbers 1 through 99.

Comment: I tried that substitution but did not do that match part properly. Just as I surmised it won't do it. Cheers. I guess it will work everywhere with every filename_image1, 2, etc.

Comment: So I tried on other files inside Notepad++ and found that there no round brackets present and the folder name was still present. It looks like this:
![image]FolderName/MarkdownFileName_image3.png

Comment: @fl0tt0tt0 answer updated to remove folder name in response to the question edit, it should have your intended behavior now

Comment: It's better now, but now it's done only on files 1-9, image10, and the rest are not changed in other files.

Comment: @fl0tt0tt0 you specified `[0-9]` in your question, are you saying you want the regex to work for any number instead?

Comment: I specified 0-9 because I didn't know it was used to match for one digit only. I need two digits, sorry. [0-9][0-9] did not work. Image number can be 10 and up to 99.

Comment: @fl0tt0tt0 my answer has been revised to meet these specifications, numbers 1 through 99 in file names will now be matched

Comment: I got it:
!\[\[.*\/(.*_image\d{1,2}\.png)\]\]

Thanks. Couldn't have done it without you.
I did it with a 'd'... What's the difference?

Comment: Happy to help :) Feel free to accept the answer if it resolved your question